# What does `#:` mean in Guile?

Tags: scheme, guile

I normally use MIT/GNU Scheme, but found some Guile code in github ([guile-2d](https://github.com/davexunit/guile-2d/blob/master/README.org)).

```
(define main-menu
  (make-scene
   "Main Menu"
   #:init create-menu
   #:enter menu-enter
   #:exit menu-exit
   #:draw draw-menu
   #:update update-menu
   #:events `((key-down . ,menu-key-down))))
```

I first checked the MIT/GNU Scheme reference, which turned up [additional notations](https://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-ref/Additional-Notations.html), but that had nothing about `#:` in it.

I then glanced through the Guile manual, and found a few mentions ([Profile Commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Profile-Commands.html#Profile-Commands), [Debugging Commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Debug-Commands.html#Debug-Commands)) that looked like it perhaps specified optional arguments? Something akin to this in Python:

```
def foo(test):
    return test

foo(bar="test")
```

Anyone know for sure what it means?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's just syntax for Guile's keyword arguments. Take a look at the [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/lambda_002a-and-define_002a.html) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

That is the keyword argument syntax introduced by [PLT Scheme 4](http://terohasu.net/blog/2008-11-15-passing-on-keyword-arguments-in-plt-scheme.html).